# Uniquely identify a particular wifi source using Android devices

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I am working on an app that would allow indoor navigation using hardware devices that emit wifi signals in large public places such as hotels and hospitals. Each location would have multiple devices and each device would be unique so that we can identify the exact location of the device/person.

For this I don't want the user to connect to the wifi, if only a scan of the network was possible which could determine the current wifi beacon the mobile is closest to would do the job. I decided to use Android's WifiManager for the task:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);

                   wifi.startScan() ;
                   List<ScanResult> mScanResults = wifi.getScanResults();
                   String s = "" ; 
                   for(ScanResult result: mScanResults){
                     Log.d("Wifi", result.SSID) ; 
                   }
```

None of the attributes for result seem to be appropriate for use as a **UID** for Wifi Beacon, I have two questions:

a) Can we use something like a BSSID for this purpose?

b) Can I write my own wifi manager class and then somehow negotiate a handshake with the wifi where it just tells me who it is without connecting? If so please share resources for doing the same.

Comment: 1. If you name the WiFi networks differently, the BSSID will be different indeed. 2. I don't understand where you want to got with this... You either connect to the network or just detect it, then locate the device when having multiple converging WiFi networks just like cell towers.

Comment: With 1) what I meant was that anybody can spoof the BSSID as well, right? What factors determine the value of the BSSID, is it secure? 

2) I want to avoid connection, if I can just retrieve the 'profile' of a device which will/can not be spoofed (by checking the uid against a server) it would make for a better implementation.

Comment: BSSID is not that secure and *can* be spoofed. That's all I know and can help with.

Comment: One mistake that you have presently done here is 
startScan() is an asynchronous call . If you call getScanResults() immediately you wont get the updated results
You need to register a system broadcast WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION
And when you receive this broadcast after calling startScan() inside that you will call getScanResults() .

if (WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(action))
  {
    List<ScanResult> mScanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
  }

Comment: You can  compare signal strength of networks using 
WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(scanResult1.level,scanResult2.level)